# Can't add values in an arraylist?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, global

Why is arrayList printing 2 times in this javafx controller code?

Example 1:

```
List<Compute> list = new ArrayList<>(); // declared as global

@FXML
public void clickSubmit() {

    int hr = Integer.parseInt(txtHours.getText());
    int min = Integer.parseInt(txtminutes.getText());
    Compute compute = new Compute(hr, min);
    list.add(compute);
    for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
        showVBox.getChildren().add(new Label(list.get(x).toString()));
        list = new ArrayList<>(copyList);
    }
```

[I have 2 values in this list. On 2nd submit, the first value was also shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL7YD.png)

So I created another ArrayList and took the copy of the origList. By doing this, this will not print 2 times on 2nd submit.

```
List<Compute> copyList = new ArrayList<>(); // declared as global

@FXML
public void clickSubmit() {
    List<Compute> origList = new ArrayList<>();
    int hr = Integer.parseInt(txtHours.getText());
    int min = Integer.parseInt(txtminutes.getText());
    Compute compute = new Compute(hr, min);
    origList.add(compute);

    for (int x = 0; x < origList.size(); x++) {
        showVBox.getChildren().add(new Label(origList.get(x).toString()));
        copyList = new ArrayList<>(origList); // I took it's copy
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2m35.png)

However, I still don't understand why is it printing 2 times on my Example 1. Also, the time will not add properly if I used Example 2. Please please help!

```
@FXML
public void clickAdd() {
Duration sum = Duration.ZERO;
for(Compute duration : list) {
sum = sum.plus(duration.getDuration());
}
System.out.println(sum);
System.out.format("%d:%02d", sum.toHours(), sum.toMinutesPart());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have a for loop in the `clickSubmit` method, so each time the submit button is clicked, the whole list will be looped through and each item will be added to the VBox.

The first time `clickSubmit` is clicked, the list will have only one element, so one label will be added to the VBox. The second time it's clicked, the list will have two elements, so two *more* labels will be added to the VBox, the first one being the one you already added the first time.

See the problem? The contents of the VBox doesn't get cleared automatically at the start of `clickSubmit`, which you might have assumed.

One solution is to only add one label each time, for the new item only:

```
public void clickSubmit() {

    int hr = Integer.parseInt(txtHours.getText());
    int min = Integer.parseInt(txtminutes.getText());
    Compute compute = new Compute(hr, min);
    list.add(compute);
    showVBox.getChildren().add(new Label(compute.toString()));
}
```

Alternatively, `clear` the VBox before adding *all* the labels:

```
public void clickSubmit() {
    // note this line:
    showVBox.getChildren().clear();
    int hr = Integer.parseInt(txtHours.getText());
    int min = Integer.parseInt(txtminutes.getText());
    Compute compute = new Compute(hr, min);
    list.add(compute);
    for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
        showVBox.getChildren().add(new Label(list.get(x).toString()));
        list = new ArrayList<>(copyList);
    }
}
```

Your Example 2 "works" because you are clearing the list (yes, that's what `origList= new ArrayList<>(copyList);` does) every time, so the list is almost always empty.

Comment: @ratRiot01 I don't really understand why you are confused, so I'll try to say a bunch of things and see if any of these make you "click". You don't need a loop because you only need to add one more label to the VBox each time the submit button is clicked. For text boxes and labels, setting their text will override the previously set value, but here, you are _adding_ a label to a VBox. This does not make the previous labels go away. The `Compute` object previously created will not be "dereferenced" either because they are stored in a list.

Comment: @ratRiot01 "By creating a loop, I can use the same object, change its value then assign it in ArrayList." That's not the purpose of a loop. I think you misunderstood what a loop is for. A loop is for running similar pieces of code multiple times. What do you mean by the "first reference" of object? It did not override the array list because you are _adding_ to the array list. Adding to a list naturally does not change the previously added elements.

Comment: I think that makes sense now. But why is the code working or not printing 2 times on Example 2 when I am still using a loop?

Comment: @ratRiot01 The loop in Example 2 will actually only run once. Because in its first iteration, you clear the contents of the list by doing `origList = new ArrayList<>(copyList);` Now `list.size()` is 0, so `x < origList.size()` is false, so the loop stops.

Comment: One last question sir... I edited my code. It was a mistake on my part. It's supposed to be copyList = new ArrayList<>(origList); ... here, I am not clearing the origList, but taking the copy of origList and assigning it to copyList... but yet it didn't print 2 times.

Comment: @ratRiot01 In Example 2, `origList` is a local variable, so it starts off empty every time `clickSubmit` is called (`List<Compute> origList = new ArrayList<>();` makes a new list). The loop will only run once, since there is only one element in the list (the element you added). The copying to `copyList` is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I greatly appreciate it.